# Set criteria to be used in multiple SQL select queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, select-query

Need to set criteria for running multiple queries, but only want to change once.  For example, want to set year, period, document so that...

```
select * from tbl1 where tbl1.yr = year and ...
select * from tbl2 where tbl2.yr = year, and ...
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify: what RDBMS

Answer (score 2):

Create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW yourview AS
SELECT * from tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT * from tbl2
```

Then query it:

```
 SELECT * FROM yourview
 WHERE tbl1.yr = year AND ...
```

You may also want to know from which table each row comes. This can be achieved by adding an extra column to the view:

```
CREATE VIEW yourview AS
SELECT 'tbl1' AS src, * from tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbl2' AS src, * from tbl2
```

Answer (score 1):

With `CTE`; Note: you should have *`same number of columns and matching datatypes from both tables`* as you are doing a blind *`union of select *`*

```
;with cte (myYear)
as (
   select @year as myYear
)
select * from table1 t1 where t1.year  in (select myYear from cte)
union all
select * from table2 t2 where t2.year  in (select myYear from cte)
```

Answer (score 1):

If they're truly different queries, not related, you may have to resort to Dynamic SQL, e.g.

```
DECLARE @sCondition VARCHAR(50)

SET @sCondition = 'yr = 2012'

DECLARE @sQuery1 VARCHAR(1000)

SET @sQuery1 = 'select * from tbl1 where ' + @sCondition

-- DECLARE other queries in similar faction OR combine multiple queries into single variable

EXEC (@sQuery1)
```